# What is the fastest way to find if there is any odd digit in a given natural number

Tags: numbers, expression, bitwise-operators

I am seeking to find the fastest way to find if there is any odd digit in any given natural number.

I seeking an expression, not a program or function or any kind of loop.

The expression should return true if there is at least one odd digit at any position of the number, return false if there is none.

eg 412 should return true as it as 1 (odd) digit at second position.
and 4820426 should return false as there is no any odd digit at any position.

Hint: use of bitwise operator does make sense

PS: this is not a homework, but this just got clicked into my mind after solving other problems.

Comment: Properties of the decimal representation of a number don't combine that well with bitwise operations, if you're asking this question about odd hexadecimal digits then yes there is a very nice solution for that, but it doesn't look like you mean that

Comment: Just out of curiosity may  i have the solution you have for hexadecimal. May be i can convert my inputs to hexadecimal if possible.

Comment: For hexadecimal you can use `(n & 0x11111111) != 0` (for a 32bit number n) the principle could be extended to numbers of arbitrary length by making that pattern longer until it is at least as long as `n`